# A set dense in $L^2(0,T; L^2_\mu(U)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $U$ be an bounded open set in $\mathbb R^n$   Banach space and $(0,T)$ a time interval. Consider the space $C^\infty_0(0,T)$ of infinitely differentiable functions with values in $\mathbb R$ and with compact support in $(0,T)$ and $L^2(0,T; L^2_\mu(U))$ the space of square Bochner integrable functions.

Does a related result hold in the Bochner space setting, namely, is
$$
\big\{f:f=\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_i v_i,\,v_i\in L^2_\mu(U),\,\varphi_i\in C^\infty_0(0,T)\big\}
$$
dense in $L^2(0,T; L^2_\mu(U))$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can identify $L^2(0,T; V)$ with the completion (w.r.t. the Bochner norm) of the tensor product $L^2(0,T) \otimes V$. Since $C_0^\infty(0,T)$ is dense in $L^2(0,T)$, $C_0^\infty(0,T) \otimes V$ (which is your set) is dense in $L^2(0,T) \otimes V$, hence, dense in the completion $L^2(0,T; V)$.